# Super Blox - level 1.7

Tags: combinatorics, video-games

I wrote a free puzzle game for Android phones, called [Super Blox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xyz.iaptest&hl=en_AU). The aim of each level is to change the colour of all blue blocks (squares) to green using the following rules:

- You can move any block or the red ball to an adjacent empty location (horizontally or vertically, but not diagonally).
- Once the red ball touches any blue blocks it instantly turns them green. This can happen to multiple blocks in one move.
- The blocks and the ball cannot leave the boundary of the level (black rectangle).

Here is the first challenging level from the game. Can you solve it in 21 moves?

[image]

Comment: Do you have in game purchase?

Comment: I do. You can buy undo and next level pack. But it is easy enough to avoid it. Also I am not sure that the purchasing works properly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a diagram of a process I took (The number in between is how many moves each step took):

> [image: Puzzle Process]
> The dark green squares are newly turned blocks from the moves taken in that step

Step 1:

> Move the red circle in either direction, I chose down but it's diagonally symmetric

Step 2:

> Move the rightmost green block up and move the red circle into its spot

Step 3:

> Move both the leftmost blocks up two spaces.

Step 4:

> Move the bottommost green block to the left and move the red circle into its spot

Step 5:

> Rotate the three pieces in the center counterclockwise, moving the red circle to the left

Step 6:

> Move the bottom 3 most blocks one to the left

Step 7:

> Rotate the three pieces in the center counterclockwise again, moving the red circle up

Step 8:

> Move the three blocks on the far right down a square

This adds up to 1+2+4+2+3+3+3+3 = 21

Comment: You got it! Very nice way to display it.